# TypeScript source maps become corrupt when debugging Aurelia CLI project in IE / VS 2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, aurelia

I recently experienced a rather frightening issue trying to debug some TypeScript code using Internet Explorer 11 / Visual Studio 2015, in an Aurelia CLI project.

I made a small change to the code, it compiled fine, but when debugging, my breakpoints were corrupted all of a sudden - the debugger worked but it was hitting totally unrelated code. I couldn't debug, basically. It seems as if the source maps had been corrupted somehow.

I then reverted the code, recompiled and the problem went away. It came back as soon as I tried the code change again, so it's not some temporary glitch in the IDE or browser.

Can anyone help me understand this problem in more detail if they've had similar issues and found a resolution? I'm really concerned about the stability of the debugging experience for developers now, if adding a single line of code can do this.

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the CLI (0.23.0)?

Comment: No I'm on 0.20.2 - I'll update to 0.23 and try again. If I update aurelia-cli, do I also need to migrate any changes to files in /aurelia_project as well? I'm not clear on the lifecycle of these project files as opposed to the NPM package itself, thanks.

Comment: Normally, there isn't anything to change as you update, but this time there is: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/blob/master/doc/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: OK I've upgraded, the source map issue seems to be fixed now, I can't reproduce anymore. I've tried upgrading the Aurelia CLI project files as per the changelog notes, but am hitting an issue with the text plugin, which I've put into this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034339/ can you have a look please?